# NetSuite Grab any inventory numbers with lowercase letters in them

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to make a saved search that shows any inventory numbers with lowercase letter(s) in it. I have tried the following formula but am not having any luck, I have tried using the match parameter but don't want to specify a position for where the lowercase letter may occur, could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to correct it?

```sql
REGEXP_INSTR({inventorynumber},'%[a-z]%')
```

I have this in a numeric formula criteria where it is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NetSuite Saved Search you do not need to use the wild card (%) with the character class ([]).  The following 2 options should work.

```
REGEXP_INSTR({entityid},'[a-z]')
REGEXP_INSTR({entityid},'[[:lower:]]')
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, this worked!

Comment: No problem!  Great that this worked for you.